# Finding and replacing using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find and replace a string when someone inputs it as a search query if they should misspell the code, for example Z0000ECEL is written as Z000ECEL it would replace it to be Z00+ECEL, this is so it finds the closest code to this and find it still even if they misspell it, I am currently using:

```
        if (Regex.IsMatch(searchWords[0], "^[a-z]+z00+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            Regex.Replace(searchWords[0], "[0]+", "*0", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }
```

I do not want to place a wildcard at the start of the string as this will bring back to many results.

Comment: should the pattern be _^z00+[a-z]+_ ?

Comment: No as the starting letter varies based on the product so I just use ^[a-z]+

Comment: in your sample there is Z000ECEL, so at first _Z000_ and then the rest letters

Comment: I want it to change Z000 to Z00*ECEL

Comment: so to simplify - you want to replace the last two zeroes in Z000 to 0*, right?

Comment: Yes basically this is what I want to do

Comment: try this one - `Regex.Replace(searchWords[0], "(?<z>z0*)0{2}", "${z}0*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this doing what you want?

```
Regex.Replace(searchWords[0], "0{3,}", "00*");
```

this will replace 3 or more zeros with "00*"

You can also combine this with your first check

```
Regex.Replace(searchWords[0], "(?<=^[a-z]+z)0{3,}", "00*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This is involving a lookbehind assertion, so the `0{3,}` will be only replaced, if there is a `^[a-z]+z` before.

Comment: This is great, thank you (actually turned out I was doing it in the wrong place that would be a lot more complicated)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, "(?i)(^[a-z]+0)0+", "$1+");
```